# General Criteria for existence of solution for a system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have dug into all the posts in the forum on this topic but haven't quite yet found a satisfying answer to my problem.
So my current problem is part of a big assignment at my college, I just need someone to shed some light on this.
The problem is as follows:
Given f and g are 2 real-valued functions defined over $\mathbb{R}$.
Consider this system of equations:
\begin{cases}
 R' & = & f(t,R,J)\\
 J' & = & g(t,R,J) 
\end{cases}
The problem asks me to find a condition on $f$ and $g$ such that the above system have a solution (not necessarily unique).

My guess is that $f$ and $g$ being continuous is sufficient. And my approach is to construct a sequence of functions $h_1$, $h_2$, ..., which are approximations using the Euler method. Then I want to prove that if the step size in the Euler method is sufficiently small, the sequence will converge to some kind of function and that function would be the solution.

However, I haven't quite figured it out yet. I hope someone would clarify 2 things:

- Is $f$ and $g$ being continuous sufficient?
- Would my approach work?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, that works. Now you need some compactness argument like Arzela-Ascoli to get the existence of a convergent subsequence in the family or sequence of Euler approximations. Note that most proofs that do not rely on the order structure of the state space work for scalar ODE as well as for systems.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you very much for taking your time! Just to be sure, can you confirm that f and g being continuous is the only condition that it needs? Sorry but I just don't want to take the wrong route from the start :(

Comment: Yes, that is sufficient for the general Peano theorem. There is a version of the theorem or its proof for scalar ODE that works by constructing upper and lower solutions without needing "higher" theorems. Otherwise just write your system for the state $Y=(R,J)^T$ for any standard ODE theory.